# Web part disappears when editing page

Tags: web-part, my-site

I have a custom tab on the MySites profile page, which displays two web parts. they only display however when I'm editing the page - when I click "Stop Editing" they disappear. It is not a javascript issue as the web part do not even appear in the source of the page.

Also, the second web part does nothing but tell the browser it must authenticate again.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The web part was audienced for a group that I was not in.